# Windows 10: How can I fix "access denied" when using mkdir

Tags: command-line

This may be a stupid question but:

Using command prompt on windows 10, when I attempt to use the command "mkdir x" I always get "Access is denied". So, I have to run cmd as an administrator every time to bypass it. Is there a more efficient process because I have to allow cmd to make changes every time and then change the directory to the one I need. I'm always on my user profile which is already my computer's administrator.

The code I currently use is here:

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop>mkdir x
```

Comment: Open command prompt as an administrator, right click on it and select run as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder C:\Users\Public is not your own profile folder, but the one that changes all profiles.

This folder (and all subfolders) are considered computer folders, rather than user folders. Because it is a change on computer level (it affects the entire computer and all users), Administrative rights are required.

If you start command prompt as administrator, the command will work without error.

If you don't want to start command prompt as administrator, you can still make a folder on your own desktop, it just won't show up on all other users' desktop.

Type in the following command to go to your own desktop folder:

```
cd /d %userprofile%\desktop
```